# Where can I find all the wallpapers ever included?

Tags: desktop-background

Is there a place where I can find all the wallpapers ever included on the Ubuntu CDs (not just the default ones)??

I remember some nice ones, like the one with the cherries. A package would be great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the following site which seems to have all of them **(from 4.10 to 10.10 only)**.

http://ubuntu.ecchi.ca/wallpapers/

Answer (score 13):

There are mainly two ways to find wallpapers included in all Ubuntu official releases: Ubuntu repositories and Ubuntu Package Search.

### From Ubuntu repositories

Ubuntu has four [repository components](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories), which are all enabled by default. The **main** component will contain wallpapers for current Ubuntu release and **universe** component will contain wallpapers for previous Ubuntu releases and other flavours.

Open a terminal and run the following command.

```
apt-cache search ubuntu wallpapers | sort -n
```

This will return a local search result: use "ubuntu wallpapers" as keywords and find package that matches with the name, then sort the result by string numerical value.

```
blubuntu-wallpapers - Blubuntu look - Wallpapers
edgy-community-wallpapers - Edgy Community Wallpapers
edgy-wallpapers - Edgy Wallpapers
edubuntu-artwork - edubuntu themes and artwork
edubuntu-wallpapers - wallpapers included in edubuntu
feisty-wallpapers - Feisty Wallpapers
gutsy-wallpapers - Gutsy Wallpapers
ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-trusty - Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers - Ubuntu GNOME Wallpapers
ubuntukylin-wallpapers-saucy - Ubuntu Kylin 13.10 Wallpapers
ubuntukylin-wallpapers-trusty - Ubuntu Kylin 14.04 Wallpapers
ubuntukylin-wallpapers - Ubuntu Kylin Wallpapers
ubuntustudio-wallpapers - Ubuntu Studio - Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-karmic - Ubuntu 9.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-lucid - Ubuntu 10.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick - Ubuntu 10.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-natty - Ubuntu 11.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric - Ubuntu 11.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-precise - Ubuntu 12.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal - Ubuntu 12.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-raring - Ubuntu 13.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy - Ubuntu 13.10 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-trusty - Ubuntu 14.04 Wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers - Ubuntu Wallpapers
xubuntu-community-wallpapers - Xubuntu community wallpapers
xubuntu-wallpapers - Xubuntu wallpapers
```

The local search result will vary by releases: 14.04 release will show above output; 16.04 release will also include wallpapers from its current and earlier releases, which are 16.04, 15.10, and 15.04.

### From Ubuntu Packages Search

For users running an older release but still want to get wallpapers for the newer releases, open a web browser and visit [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

> This site provides you with information about all the packages available in the Ubuntu Package archive.
>
> [image: Using the Ubuntu Package Search]

Scroll down until you reach "Search package directories". The suggested search options are:

- Keyword: ubuntu wallpapers
- Search on: [x] Package name only
- Distribution: any
- Section: any

Click **Search** to see the result.

```
Package blubuntu-wallpapers

* trusty (14.04LTS) (x11): Blubuntu look - Wallpapers [universe]
    0.3.1: all
* xenial (16.04LTS) (x11): Blubuntu look - Wallpapers [universe]
    0.3.1: all
* bionic (18.04LTS) (x11): Blubuntu look - Wallpapers [universe]
    0.3.1: all
* cosmic (18.10) (x11): Blubuntu look - Wallpapers [universe]
    0.3.1: all
* disco (x11): Blubuntu look - Wallpapers [universe]
    0.3.1: all

Package edubuntu-wallpapers

* trusty (14.04LTS) (gnome): wallpapers included in edubuntu [universe]
    14.03.1: all
* xenial (16.04LTS) (gnome): wallpapers included in edubuntu [universe]
    15.12.1: all
* bionic (18.04LTS) (gnome): wallpapers included in edubuntu [universe]
    15.12.1: all
* cosmic (18.10) (gnome): wallpapers included in edubuntu [universe]
    15.12.1: all
* disco (gnome): wallpapers included in edubuntu [universe]
    15.12.1: all

...
```

The result will include packages with name that matches with "ubuntu wallpapers" keywords. It is also possible for users to download the DEB packages from the links in the search result and install to any release in use, since there are no dependencies for installing the wallpapers.

### Search result discrepancy

> Wallpapers from some releases are missing from the search result

Ubuntu Package Search will show all available packages regardless of the release. In comparison, the local search result from Ubuntu repositories depends on the release that is currently used.

For example, 14.04 release *does not* show `ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-*` in the Ubuntu repositories because Ubuntu MATE became an official flavour from 15.04 release. With Ubuntu Package Search, you can find such missing packages easily.

> Searching with "ubuntu wallpaper" does not show certain packages

The suggested search option will show most relevant results. The keywords will match packages that contain wallpapers for all official flavours, given that the names were derived from and contain "ubuntu" itself: *Ubuntu*, L*ubuntu*, K*ubuntu*, X*ubuntu*, *Ubuntu* MATE etc.

Therefore, some wallpapers are missing from the search result because of different package naming, such as wallpapers for Plasma Workspace and Shimmer Project.

This answer is applicable to all supported Ubuntu releases at any time.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a search in synaptic or software center for `wallpaper`, you should find a number of packages including fiesty and karmic, and these should include most of the wallpapers you are seeking. The artwork section of the ubuntu wiki ([here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork)) might also have them. If you look on [this page](http://www.flickr.com/groups/ubuntu-artwork/), you should also be able to find those + some great extras.

Hope that helps! Enjoy your wallpapers ^^ =)!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command to install all the wallpapers from Ubuntu 9.10 to 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-karmic ubuntu-wallpapers-lucid ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick ubuntu-wallpapers-natty ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric ubuntu-wallpapers-precise ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal ubuntu-wallpapers-raring ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy ubuntu-wallpapers-trusty
```

Go to [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/download-all-ubuntu-community.html) for more info

Answer (score 2):

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers_0.29.tar.gz
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/0.31/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers_0.31.tar.gz
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Archives

Answer (score 2):

I found this wallpapers:

- [4.10 Warty Warthog, 5.04 Hoary Hedgehog, 6.10 Edgy Eft, 7.04 Feisty Fawn, 7.10 Gutsy Gibbon](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=SHMYQ7RV)
- 5.10 Breezy Badger
- 6.06 LTS Dapper Drake
- 8.04 LTS Hardy Heron
- [8.10 Intrepid Ibex](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-8-10-Has-a-Brand-New-Wallpaper-95451.shtml)
- [9.04 Jaunty Jackalope](http://www.blogsdna.com/2735/ubuntu-904-jaunty-jackalope-brand-new-wallpapers.htm)
- [9.10 Karmic Koala](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-9-10-039-s-New-Wallpapers-and-More-122551.shtml)
- [10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx](http://news.softpedia.com/news/The-New-Wallpapers-of-Ubuntu-10-04-LTS-139925.shtml)
- [10.10 Maverick Meerkat](http://news.softpedia.com/news/The-New-Wallpapers-and-Theme-of-Ubuntu-10-10-153934.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

From the [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) sub-site you can find them all.

The package `ubuntu-wallpapers` from the latest release will have all wallpapers from release 9.10 to date.

Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/323574/58950).

Wallpapers from releases 4.10 to 9.04 can be obtained from http://ubuntu.ecchi.ca/wallpapers/ [as indicated by Mark Rooney in his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/11489/58950).

Answer (score 1):

You can install all of the wallpapers from 9.10 forwards by running this single command (this should apply to ***all*** future Ubuntu releases):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-suggests ubuntu-wallpapers
```

This will install the ubuntu-wallpapers metapackage, which also suggests the packages for all the other wallpapers.

As for the pre-modern (4.10 - 9.04) era of Ubuntu, these wallpapers are available [here](http://ubuntu.ecchi.ca/wallpapers/).

You can get some of these wallpapers through the official repo by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install feisty-wallpapers gusty-wallpapers \
                     edgy-wallpapers edgy-community-wallpapers
```

There are also extra wallpapers that may or may not have been distributed with the CDs, but they do exist on the repository.

```
sudo apt-get install blubuntu-wallpapers peace-wallpapers tropic-wallpapers
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the source code of all wallpaper packages:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-wallpapers
```

The newly created `ubuntu-wallpapers` directory should have them all.

Or browse them online at Launchpad: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/ubuntu-wallpapers/wily/files

(Replace `wily` with the newest release's codename as time passes.)

Comment: `bzr branch lp:ubuntu-wallpapers` is an excellent suggestion to be able to browse all of the wallpapers... Although the wallpapers are downloaded locally, so it is not online, you can actually view them in your file manager.