# How do I install wallpapers from older releases?

Tags: desktop-background

I have currently installed 12.04 and I really like the wallpapers of 11.10. How do I install it in 12.04?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can install the wallpapers of the 13.10 by running this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy
```

or using Software Center   [image: Install via the software center]

For other older Ubuntu versions, replace `saucy` with

- `raring` for 13.04
- `quantal` for 12.10
- `precise` for 12.04
- `oneiric` for 11.10
- `natty` for 11.04,
- `maverick` for 10.10,
- `lucid` for 10.04,
- `karmic` for 9.10,

Wallpapers for Ubuntu version 6.10, 7.04 and 7.10 also available. To Install edgy wallpapers use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install edgy-wallpapers
```

for feisty (1.04) and gutsy (7.10) replace `edgy-wallpapers` with `feisty-wallpapers` and `gutsy-wallpapers` respectively.

For convenience for users looking to download ALL the wallpapers:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-* edgy-wallpapers feisty-wallpapers gutsy-wallpapers
```

- [Where can I find all the wallpapers ever included?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11447/where-can-i-find-all-the-wallpapers-ever-included)

Answer (score 9):

You can try :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers*
```

You can use wildcard `*` to install all ubuntu-wallpapers quickly.

Comment: What folder are they downloaded to?

Comment: /usr/share/backgrounds