# Can I download & Install the wallpapers from 12.10 on 12.04.1?

Tags: desktop-background

I was googling regarding Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal); pretty much liked the wallpapers. Just out of curiosity, can I install the wallpapers from a higher release (12.10) on a previous release Precise (12.04.1) without upgrading to 12.10.

I have tried the following:-

```
ankit@stream:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal
[sudo] password for ankit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal
```

I have followed this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121379/how-do-i-install-wallpapers-from-older-releases); but this for installing wallpapers from previous releases on the current release.

Any ideas how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Available here http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/12-new-wallpapers-land-in-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: thanks chris; but I dont just want to download but I also want to install the wallpapers from Quantal on Precise

Comment: OMG!Ubuntu! article pointed to **0.35.0** (since superseded).  Instead use: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers_0.35.2.tar.gz and https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers_0.35.2.dsc

Comment: thanks david. I would appreciate a feedback from a person giving me a downvote.

Comment: @Ankit I found a way of doing it but it was very manual involving adding the backgrounds into /usr/share/backgrounds and editing 2 .xml files. I'm sure someone more learned than I can come up with an easier way

Comment: thanks a lot Chris :), could you please share the xml files that needs to be edited.

Comment: My editing was done so that I kept the existing 12.04 backgrounds as well as the new 12.10 ones not sure if you want the same. Also not sure how to share files on here

Comment: I am sorry I wanted to know the names of the xml files to be eidted. :)

Comment: Sorry you will find them usr/share/background/contest/precise.xml this one you will need to edit to be able to set the background to automatically change after a set period of time. And usr/share/gnome-background-properties/precise-wallpapers.xml. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Synaptic Package Manager and type Wallpapers into the search field. All the wallpapers you are looking for are in there. Just click the little check box to mark them for installation. This way worked for me to get previous and current Ubuntu wallpapers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes just search in the Software centre for "Wallpaper".

You should get the default papers going all the way back to karmic or something like that.

I install them from other releases.

[Source code](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers)

[Launchpad Ubuntu Wallpapers](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-wallpapers)

Comment: I can't find them.