# How to download previous Ubuntu wallpapers?

Tags: desktop-background, design

I was curious if it's possible to download the default wallpapers from the previous Ubuntu versions. I know that I can probably Google them, but I'd rather download them from one of Ubuntu's official sites. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install wallpapers from older releases?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121379/how-do-i-install-wallpapers-from-older-releases)

Comment: I searched previous ubuntu wallpaper download and the question in the link appeared first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install wallpapers from past Ubuntu versions (or other Ubuntu flavors) by installing the packages that contain the wallpapers.

For example:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-wallpapers-raring
```

or

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-wallpapers-natty
```

etc.

You can get the full list by searching in `synaptic` (you may need to install it) or from the command line with

```
apt search wallpapers
```