# How do I install 10.04 wallpapers on 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, desktop-background

I've been trying `"sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric"`, using natty, maverick, lucid and karmic as shown in

[How do I install wallpapers from older releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121379/how-do-i-install-wallpapers-from-older-releases)

but I keep getting `"can't locate the package ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric"`

Also used the info here: [Where can I find all the wallpapers ever included?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11447/where-can-i-find-all-the-wallpapers-ever-included) but there is no package to be installed and the pics are a little low res for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't.. The wallpaper package is only available for Precise and Quantal. If someone possibly packages it into PPA, then you might be in for some luck.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking this might be an answer since I saw the answers I posted before. Thanks for your answer and your time.

Answer (score 0):

As jokerdino mentioned , it is only available for Precise and Quantal. You can download the .deb package here.

[ubuntu-wallpapers (0.31.3) lucid](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers_0.31.3_all.deb)

Comment: The wallpaper package is only available for Precise and Quantal. Sorry..

Comment: Than you! I've downloaded and tried to install this but, Ubuntu software center says that I have a newer version installed already... I've installed some screensavers, not wall papers. I'll try to figure it out. Thans for your answer and for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Very Easy, Booting any old version go to /user/share/backgrounds and you will find release Wallpapers of that version. Copy to USB drive and use it.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty "obvious" but i did NEVER think about this. I've the boot CD's, so I'll give it a try. Thanks Ketan,for your answer and time, this seems to be the way to go for me.

Comment: vote pls and choose as best