# Where can I download the default wallpaper of Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, desktop-background

Where can I download the default wallpaper of Ubuntu 13.04 from an official source?

I can download all the other wallpapers that come along with it by either going to Launchpad or installing the package "ubuntu-wallpapers-raring".

But the default one seems to impossible to get a hold of (from the official Ubuntu website(s)).

Answer (score 1):

you can get the wallpapers from this OMG! Ubuntu! link http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/ubuntu-13-04-winning-wallpapers-announced

Comment: Nope, the default wallpaper is nowhere to be found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Default is here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/ubuntu-13-04-default-wallpaper-revealed 
No, you can't get it officially, but OMG! Ubuntu! is pretty close.

Comment: Having posted the above, I can't seem to download it (at least, not in Firefox 22, Nightly (25) or Chrome)...

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu wallpapers from older releases can be installed from the Software Center, but I guess you want the 13.04 wallpapers and have installed an earlier Ubuntu release (perhaps 12.04 LTS?).

Well, simply go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-wallpapers and, from the right-hand panel, select the link `[ubuntu-wallpapers_13.04.0daily13.03.20.orig.tar.gz]` under "Download Source Package ubuntu-wallpapers:".

This will download a 26MiB file containing all wallpapers from release 9.10 to date, including the default wallpaper under the name `warty-final-ubuntu.png`. Note that this seems to be a `.jpg` file with `.png` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can install old Ubuntu wallpapers using installing the ubuntu-wallpapers-(version) package. For example, if you use the terminal, you can type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-raring`, to get Ubuntu Raring's wall papers.